# Alternar visibilidad de dos divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

como puedo hacer para alternar la visibilidad de dos divs, es decir (si "item1" show "item2" hide y viceversa?

```html
<div><a>Item 1</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item2 y ocultar Item1 -->
<div><a>Item 2</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item1 y ocultar Item2 -->
```

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando Jquery podemos hacer los siguiente.

```js
$("div").click(function(){  
  $("div").show();
  $(this).hide();  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a>Item 1</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item2 y ocultar Item1 -->
<div style="display: none;"><a>Item 2</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item1 y ocultar Item2 -->
```

Comment: Gracias weimar! Sencillo, y funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Asuimiendo que tenemos inicialmente uno de los divs oculto por ejemplo:

```
<div><a>Item 1</a></div>
<div class="display:none"><a>Item 2</a></div>
```

bastará con seleccionar ambos y ejecutar el método [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) en ambos:

```
$("#div1,#div2").toggle();
```

`.toggle()` muestra el elemento si está oculto o lo oculta si está visible.

#### Ejemplo completo:

```js
$("#div1,#div2").click(function(){
  $("#div1,#div2").toggle();
});
```

```css
#div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"><a>Item 1</a></div>
<div id="div2"><a>Item 2</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma puede ser:

```js
$("#div1").click(function(){  
  $('#div2').toggle(); 
  $('#div1').toggle(); 
});
$("#div2").click(function(){  
 $('#div1').toggle();
 $('#div2').toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show" id="div1"><a>Item 1</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item2 y ocultar Item1 -->
<div style="display: none;" id="div2"><a>Item 2</a></div> <!-- Click para mostrar Item1 y ocultar Item2 -->
```